# Is there a cyclic subgroup C of S8 such that the interval lattice [C,S8] is distributive?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lattice-orders, gap

I've checked by hand that for any $n \le 7$, there is a cyclic subgroup $C$ of $S_n$ such that the intermediate subgroups lattice $\mathcal{L}(C \subset S_n)$ is distributive.

*Question:* Is it the same for $S_8$? and next for any $S_n$?

I've tried to check with GAP but after two days, the computation is not yet finished.
Is there a way to access to the [atlas of subgroups lattice](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~tconnor/atlaslat/) of Thomas Connor and Dimitri Leemans with GAP, or at least to [their algorithm](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~tconnor/atlaslat/algosublat.txt) translated in GAP (it is now written for MAGMA)?

Comment: But it if turns out that the answer is yes, then you will presumably immediately ask the same question for $S_9$!

Comment: @DerekHolt: I believe it is not true for $S_8$, but if it is true, then I will ask for $S_n$  for all $n$.

Comment: Are you able easily to reduce the list of candidates for the cyclic subgroup $C$? I would guess, for example, that $|C|=2$ is not possible?

Comment: @DerekHolt: yes there is a way to reduce because a distributive lattice with n minimal elements has a length of at least n, and an intermediate subgroups lattice of length $n$ has an index of at least $2^n$. Now $8! \sim 2^{15}$, so if $C$ admits more than $16$ minimal overgroups, $[C,S_8]$ can't be distributive. Thanks to the atlas, it follows that $|C|≤3$ is not possible (and by improving the argument, I believe we can go up to $4$).

Comment: Is it not true that if $N_{S_n}(C)/C$ contains a Klein $4$-group, then $[C,N_{S_n}(C)]$ cannot be distributive, and hence neither can $[C,S_n]$?

Comment: @DerekHolt: Yes right, because a lattice is distributive iff it contains no sublattice equivalent to the diamond lattice (as for the Klein group)  or the pentagon lattice.

Comment: The lattice computation should be easily doable. Can you indicate what is not yet finished?

Comment: @ahulpke: I don't know what happened, perhaps I have not installed the good package. Is there a package with the subgroups lattice of the small groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, we can assume that $N_{S_8}(C)/C$ does not contain a Klein $4$-group.

In fact that leaves only two possible $C$:

1. $\langle (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) \rangle$ of order $7$; and
2. $\langle (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7) \rangle$ of order $10$.

I can rule out the first one.

Let $H = \langle (1,2,3,4,5,6,7),(2,7)(3,6)(4,5) \rangle$ be dihedral of order $14$.

Let $K = \langle (1,2,3,4,5,6,7),(1,7)(2,5)(3,8)(4,6) \rangle$ be a Frobenius group of order $56$.

Then you can check that $\langle H,K \rangle = S_8$, so $A_8 \cap \langle H,K \rangle = A_8$.

But $A_8 \cap H = C$ and $A_8 \cap K = K$, so $\langle A_8 \cap H, A_8 \cap K \rangle = K$, and the lattice is not distributive.

I can now also rule out the $C_{10}$ case with $C = (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7) \rangle$. Consider the following three subgroups, all containing $C$:

(i) $H_1 = S_7$, the stabiliser of $8$ in $S_8$.

(ii) $H_2 = S_5 \times S_3$ with orbits $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\{6,7,8\}$.

(iii) $H_3 = S_6 \times S_2$ with orbits $\{1,2,3,4,5,8\}$ and $\{6,7 \}$.

Then any two of these generate $S_8$, but the intersection of any two of them is the same subgroup $S_5 \times C_2$, so we have one of the standard non-distributive sublattices.